# Mavericks installation stuck at 18 minutes mark

Tags: macos

I am trying to reinstall Mavericks an 27 inch, Mid-2011 iMac[image]

The hardisk has been reformatted, and I have created one partition Mac-HDD in it.

I have created a Mavericks usb installer using this command:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia \
--volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app --nointeraction
```

Can you suggest anything I can try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can **show the install log by pressing cmd-L**. Make sure you're showing all messages and look at the bottom of the log. This may give you a hint as to what's happened (or happening).

Comment: I have tried cmd-L but it does not respond. Nothing happened. Likewise there is reaction when I clicked 'About OSX installer' etc

Comment: @Anthony It's probably crashed then… You will probably need to interrupt the install and try again, but with the installer log open.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to repartition the HD and then do a repair. It is possible you have some bad blocks on the HD and it needs to be replaced.

You could also do a secure wipe and do a one pass wipe with zeros, under security options. If that stops partway through I would blame the drive.